# Not respecting the 3rd rule of a LL(1) grammar

Tags: formal-grammars, ll-k

I'm trying to build a grammar that violate only the 3rd rule. I'm trying to figure out what kind of grammar would not respect that.

I think the grammar has to be left-recursive to not respect it.

if $\beta \Rightarrow^* \epsilon$ then $\alpha$ does not derive any string beginning with a terminal in $\mathop {FOLLOW}(A)$. Where $A \to \alpha \mid \beta$

Am I right to think that?

Comment: What "rules" are you talking about? Presumably it is enough to just add a production (or two) that violate the rule.

Comment: Added the rule.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following:

$\begin{align}
  S &\to A a \\
  A &\to a \mid \epsilon
\end{align}$

Comment: So it has to be left recursive?

Comment: @Laura this isn't recursive (no right hand side contains the non-terminal at the left), even less left-recursive

Comment: ok so FOLLOW(A) = {a,$} in this case. And FIRST(S) = {a}

Comment: @Laura, what is important is that $A \Rightarrow^* \epsilon$, $\mathop{FIRST}(A) = \{a\}$ and $\mathop{FOLLOW}(A) = \{a\}$, so $\mathop{FIRST}(A) \cap \mathop{FOLLOW}(A) \ne \varnothing$